# Detect sentence structure

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence, grammar

Is there a way to translate a sentence to Noun, pronoun, adjective, verb, adverb, conjunction, preposition, and interjection?

I am looking to do this in PHP, I do understand that there might be no definite answer to this question but I am still looking for the latest library that can accomplish this as closely as possible, ideally in PHP.

Comment: I don't think anyone does cutting-edge research into natural language processing using PHP.

Comment: The correct search term is *Part-of-speech tagging*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Ian Barber's PHP implementation of a [Brill Parser](http://phpir.com/part-of-speech-tagging/). This is an English language implementation. I know there are similar algorithms for non-English languages (you haven't specified a language) but I can't provide any links for those.

Comment: I am looking for English and thanks! That was quite helpful, are there any ones that use that Hidden Markov Model which I keep hearing about? Thanks in advance.